# Granting rights to Windows domain Users in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, likewise-open

I've connected an Ubuntu 9.10 server to my Windows domain with Likewise Open. I am able to log into the server with my domain account (as DOMAIN\user), but my administrative rights don't carry over. How can I grant admin rights to domain user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I asked a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/151596) and found an answer that may help. If you give the user or group sudo access, you should get full administrative privileges.

Edit your sudoers file using the following command (must be run from an account that already has sudo privileges on the machine):

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add a line to the end of the file like the following:

```
%<YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE>\\Domain^Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

This gives full sudo (essentially administrative) privileges to all users in the Domain Admins group from your domain.

If I remember correctly, the % at the beginning specifies that it's a group. You can also specify a specific user to give administrative privileges to. I believe you just leave off the leading %, but I'm not positive about that without looking up the sudoers syntax... I think it's something like:

```
<YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE>\\miquella ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Hope this helps!

---

**Note:** Be aware that setting the permissions in this way gives the users in question full administrative capabilities on the computer! They will be able to run anything as the root user (but this is typically what you want if you're giving the Domain Admins group administrative privileges).