# Map the 'Domain Admins' group into the local Ubuntu 'admin' group

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, likewise-open

I have configured an Ubuntu 10.04 box to connect to our domain (Windows 2003 R2) using Likewise-Open. All the users can authenticate as expected. However, the domain administrators do not have administrative privileges to the machine.

After working at this for a few hours, I've determined what I think may be a solution: if I map the 'Domain Admins' group from the Active Directory into the local 'admin' group, the users should get the appropriate permissions. But I have no idea how to do that. Does this even sound like the correct approach?

A [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/129201) was asked on StackOverflow and then migrated here. But it was never answered as it was recommended to be asked here instead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I originally thought you would have to "map" the Domain Admins group to the local admin group to get it to work properly. As it turns out, all you have to do is give the Domain Admins group sudo access.

Modify your sudoers file using the following command (must be run with administrative privileges, of course):

```
sudo visudo
```

And add the following line to the end of the file:

```
%<YOUR_DOMAIN_HERE>\\Domain^Admins ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

This will give all users in the Domain Admins group on your domain administrative privileges on Ubuntu.